# Can someone give me an intuition of congeniality in multiple imputation?

Tags: r, bayesian, multiple-imputation

As the title says. I read a lot about congeniality of Bayesian models (e.g. Meng, 1994) and I do know some definitions, but I don't feel I can get grip on what happens when models are congenial or uncongenial. My goal is to write an R script that shows the difference (numerically), but I am not that far yet.

Is there anyone who can explain intuitively what happens with uncongenial models?